# How to count records in given interval?

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

I have a table with **created** column. I need to check if there at least one record that was created less then a minute ago, from last record with same **user_id**. E.g.

```
|            created|user_id|
|2020-01-01T22:22:22|      1|
|2020-01-01T22:22:44|      1|
```

^ Matches my clause. Created in one minute interval.

```
|            created|user_id|
|2020-01-01T22:22:22|      1|
|2020-01-01T22:24:44|      1|
```

^ Not matches, created in more than one minute interval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `distinct on` and window functions:

```
select distinct on (user_id) 
    user_id,
    created_at 
        <= lag(created_at) over(partition by user_id order by created_at) + interval '1' minute as flag
from mytable
order by user_id, created_at desc
```

This gives you one record per `user_id`, with a boolean column called `flag` that indicates whether the last but one `created_at` is one minute older or less than the latest `created_at`.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2e056a0b7cd128c5eaed5adac920423d)**.

Sample data:

```
created_at          | user_id
:------------------ | ------:
2020-01-01 22:22:22 |       1
2020-01-01 22:22:44 |       1
2020-01-01 22:22:22 |       2
2020-01-01 22:24:44 |       2
```

Results:

```
user_id | flag
------: | :---
      1 | t   
      2 | f
```

Comment: is it save to use on table with 2mil rows? I mean, thats not going to hang my db?

Comment: @senloa: please describe the problem that you are having with the results of this query.

Comment: its not working, i have 3 records with more than 1 minute range, and with different user_id, and its still matches..

Comment: @senloa: I added a fiddle to my answer. This appears to work as intended.